# Using Aggregate classes with Multiple Files - C++

Tags: c++

I am having an issue getting a class to properly recognize an aggregate class
using multiple files.  The code works if everything is in one file, but when I try to use multiple files it will not recognize the aggregate classes as classes.

```
#include <string>
#include "CInvoice.h"
#include "personType.h"
#include "dateType.h"

using namespace std;

class CInvoicePersonDate : public CInvoice
{
private:
    personType customer;
    dateType purchDate;
```

This is what the start of my derived class header looks like.  It is not registering "persontype" and "dateType" as classes. I am sure that the header files are not spelled incorrectly.  I am not sure whether I am forgetting to add some more code to make this work or whatever else the problem might be. If you need more information to assist me, please let me know.

Comment: Please post a short, complete and compilable example. What is `dataType`? Or `personType`?

Comment: Unless you post the contents of `personType.h` and `dateType.h` we will not be able to help you. Also, post your compilation command.